# PrimeVue component in Vue3 Custom Element has no access to $primevue global variable

Tags: vuejs3, web-component, custom-element, primevue

I have a XYZ Vue 3 component I am generating as a custom element (web component to be used by other, Angular app). The XYZ component has many subcomponents, including PrimeVue's `<Dropdown />`. This Dropdown uses the global property `$primevue` to get a config for `zIndex`.

It works in the standard Vue3 environment, as the global `app.globalProperties.config.$primevue` is auto injected to all components and accessible in the `this` context.

However, when generating the custom element, `$primevue.config.modal.zIndex` is undefined.

How do I make the global properties accessible to PrimeVue components (that I cannot edit) when generating the custom element?

I'm trying to extend the `defineCustomElement()` method to define custom elements, but didn't find the proper method to access all the subcomponents, PrimeVue's components specifically and to "inject" into them `$primevue` variable.